# Как использовать drag and drop C# macos

Tags: c#, macos, .net-core, .net

Как реализовать drug and drop файла в приложение написанном на C# под macos? Официальный пример drug and drop видел, но там drug and drop внутри приложения. Можно ли как-то сделать события как в windows forms?

Comment: Консольное приложение?

Comment: Приложение оконное, там пара кнопок и пара NSTextView

Comment: А фреймворк какой для UI? Авалония? Ксамарин?  Drag&drop - это часть UI фреймворка обычно.

Comment: Cocoa вроде как, интерфейс набросал в xcode

Comment: [Xamarin.Mac - Drag and Drop Example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/mac-samples/draganddropexample/) - возможно, это вам поможет. Если хотите получить точный ответ, то укажите, отредактировав вопрос, что именно вы используете, какие технологии, фреймворки, библиотеки?